# why does my ë, ï, ö etc. look different at my website

Tags: html, fonts

I use a font called NeoTech for my website. It looks nice, but the letters with a " above it, like: ë, ö, ï etc. are looking different.

Is it a problem with my font, or am I doing something wrong.
I already tried the using the code for these letters like this: `&#235;`

I hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are making mistake in somewhere. I have checked the website (https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/neo-tech/) for compatibility of the font with Scandinavian alphabets and it looks compatible.

[image: Screenshot of the result]

If you can share the link of your website or HTML code, I can help you to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see that the NeotTech font thaht I am using does not support that "letters does not support ë letters.